# jquery anchor should come in the middle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the following code to focus on the anchor when clicked

```
$('#mydiv').click(function() {
  location.href="#blah";
});
```

it does focus on that anchor but the issue is that part of anchor towards top of the screen. Is there a way I can kinda keep it in the middle?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've done in the past:

Basically, you measure the height of the window, and the position of the div and scroll to a point which puts the div in the center of the screen.

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  location.href="#blah";

  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var elementHeight = $("#blah").height();

  var elementPosition = $("#blah").position();
  var elementTop = elementPosition.top;

  var toScroll = (windowHeight / 2) - (elementHeight / 2);

  window.scroll(0,(elementTop - toScroll));
});
```

Comment: gives me this error Uncaught Dimensions: jQuery collection is empty
errorjquery.dimensions.min.js:20
$.fn.extend.heightjquery.dimensions.min.js:12
(anonymous function)SplitScreenView.php:2504
d.event.handlejquery-1.5.1.min.js:16
d.event.add.k.handle.m

Comment: my bad.  You don't need to call `$(window)` , just `window.scroll`.

Comment: its not giving any errors but it doesnt scroll to the anchor either. Could it be because I am in nested divs?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. :/ Do you have the `e.preventDefault` added?  If not, it could be going to the link and not actually running the script.  Are you stating the script after the page is fully loaded (`$.ready()`)?  Could you post some of your code?

Comment: I am adding the code in document ready. So the code works after the page loads completely. It just doesnt do anything for some reason

Comment: actually there is an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
(anonymous function)SplitScreenView.php:2507
d.event.handlejquery-1.5.1.min.js:16
d.event.add.k.handle.m'

Comment: Are you clicking an `<img/>`, `<a href/>` or a `<div/>`?  I had issued directly clicking on a div but when I used an `<a>` tag it worked just fine, as you can see in the demo I posted.  I'm not sure how much more I can help you without some code.  Do you have a Fiddle or a page you're working on that I could see?

Comment: The `e` comes into play when you begin the function on the click event. You should have `$('#mydiv').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();` like in my code.  The `e` is defined when the function is instantiated.  Are you using exactly the code I posted or some modification?  Could you post what code you're using?  If not, all that I can make are guesses...

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to get anchor position, window size. Then you can scroll to the desired position.

```
        $('#mydiv').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // to prevent default anchor behaviour
            var target_offset_top = $("#blah").offset().top;
            var window_height = document.body.clientHeight;
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target_offset_top - window_height/2});
        });
```